# How to add a Date/Time to video capture?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I want to record video with Date/Time (put/draw current time and date on the each frame in some corner).

I din't really found any solution. I saw some similar questions here, but they doesn't have answers.

So I want to use `MediaRecorder` class to record video (I already implemented this) and somehow add Date/Time at each frame so later I could open recorded video with some video player and see this Date/Time.

Comment: There is nothing built into Android for this.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, could you please suggest where to look then? do I need some library for this? mb `javacv` or is it possible to extend some camera/mediarecorder class and edit byte/frames before it will be added to output video file?

Comment: I would have your server post-process the video, adding in the time overlay. Trying to do that on a mobile device will be *very* slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add text into original video file, it will not be that simple. You need external tools to handle this, for example FFMPEG. this links give you more info about this topic: [How to add text on video recording?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14715188/1235910) and [How to embed text while recording video in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735464/how-to-embed-text-while-recording-video-in-android)